# AttributeError in a python script that performs a data transfer

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql

There is a Python script that moves data from one SQL Server database table to a Postgresql database table. This works for most tables and this is the method that performs this operation:

```
def move_data(self, my_job=None):
        if my_job:
            self.job = my_job
        chunk = self.job.get('chunk_size', 1000)
        tbl_size = self.get_cur_job_size()

        self.create_tbl()
        logging.info("processing %s", self.job.get('name', self.job_name))
        message = "invalid chunk value in {t}".format(t=self.job.get('name'))
        assert(isinstance(chunk, int)), message

        for i in range(1, tbl_size + 1, chunk):
            start = i
            end = start + chunk - 1
            if end > tbl_size:
                end = tbl_size
            logging.info("Working on range {0} to {1}".format(start, end))

            self.data = self.build_from_data_paged(i, end)

            if len(self.data) == 0:
                break

            self.fill_temp_table_paged()
        return True
```

However, for one table (that doesn't seem to be different from the others) this operation fails, and I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What could be causing this ?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the error? looks like `my_job` parameter is passed as None for one of the calls. You are setting `self.job` only when `my_job` is not None. And `self.job` seems to be None as well, so on the next line `self.job.get()` would fail with error.

Comment: As the user mentioned above, the issue lies with how your conditional works for setting `self.job`. if its none it doesnt set the object attribute of `job` but the line below is `chunk = self.job.get('chunk_size', 1000)` is still called, where the attribute is likely to be of type none. To delve more into the error, you need to provide us the table, as otherwise there's no way to tell what could be cauisng this.